# SQL Server calculate percentage or decimal in complex expression

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT
    person,
    (CAST( /* I tried with and without CAST */
     COUNT(`something`) / /* success count is numerator */
    (COUNT(`something`) +
    SUM(case when `something` is null then 1 else 0 end)) AS DECIMAL(3,1))
    /* sum of success + failure counts is denominator. */
    ) success_ratio,
    SUM(case when `something` is null then 1 else 0 end) fail_count,
    COUNT(`something`) success_count
FROM 
    `table`
GROUP BY 
    person
ORDER BY 
    person
```

In my output, the `success_count` and `fail_count` both output integers.

When I first tried to create the fraction without `CAST`, I got mostly `0`, with `1` a few times. I tried `CAST`ing, but now it's just `0.0` and `1.1`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is you are casting the value of the integer division rather than the the individual parts

You can use a subquery to make things a little easier to read, and by using 1.0 or 0.0 in your case statement you can force the fields to be floating point

```
SELECT person, 
       success_count / ( success_count + fail_count) success_rate,
       fail_count, success_count 
FROM (
  SELECT person,
  (
    SUM(case when `something` is null then 1.0 else 0.0 end) fail_count,
    SUM(case when `something` is null then 1.0 else 0.0 end) success_count
  FROM `table`
  GROUP BY person
) x 
ORDER BY person
```